# Determined labels and reconstruction conjecture

Tags: graph-theory, graph-reconstruction

In the reconstruction conjecture $(RC)$, if we know the $k$, $0\leq k \leq n$ labels of the vertices, then $RC$ is true.

Do we know the minimum $k$ that the above statement is true?

Do we have any research in this direction?

Comment: RC is that $k=0$, so I doubt that we know

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: if $k=n$, RC is true. Also, if $k=n-1$, then RC is true. It seems that if we have the labels of half of vertices, again RC is true. But I do not have proof for the last case yet.

Comment: But you ask about minimal $k$. Conjecturally the minimal $k$ is 0.

Comment: We do not know the conjecture is true for $k=0$. I want to find the minimum $k$ that the conjecture can be proved. We know that this minimum is not zero, since RC is still open.

Comment: Easy for $k=n-2$. Nice question.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks, dear McKay. You are right and this case is easy. But I can not see the general strategy yet.